# Detect if Chrome Frame BHO is enabled

Tags: google-chrome-frame

I have the following code to detect to see if CF BHO is enabled, but unfortunately it didn't work out, it alway returns "automation server failed to create obj"

```
  var activexGoogleFrameBho = new ActiveXObject('ChromeFrame.Bho');
  if (activexGoogleFrameBho) {
    ...
  }
```

My user agent and page header are as following:

```
  mozilla/4.0(compatible; msie 8.0; windows nt 6.1; wow64; trident/4.0;
  chromeframe/32.0.1700.107; slcc2; .net clr 2.0.50727; .net4.0c; .net4.0e)

  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge,chrome=IE8'/>
```

any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can detect the helper object itself though to see if the current page is loaded in chromeframe you can check if `window.externalHost` exists.

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/understanding-chrome-frame-user-agent#TOC-From-the-script-on-the-web-page

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this in IE7 but the variable always returns 'undefined'. Is this only applies to Chrome not other browsers? It seems this is what indicated in the above link.

Comment: The link is about the Chrome Frame-plugin and how to detect it. I'm no expert on it though but I've used the above solutions myself before and it worked fine (ie `if(window.externalHost) {alert('In a Chrome Frame!'; }`).